# Creating an overlapping semi-transparent toolbar button that doesn't get bisected by tool bar

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

I'm creating a user interface with a green, oversized camera start/stop button that sits atop a toolbar:

[image: UI Screenshot]

Thus far, I've been using [yoichitgy/EEToolbarCenterButton](https://github.com/yoichitgy/EEToolbarCenterButton) to implement this, and it seemed like exactly what I wanted at first.

The UI designer has specifically asked for the button to be transparent. They also want the toolbar behind it to be "cut out" in such a way that you don't see the toolbar behind the button. This is an illustration of how the button should work.

[image: This is an illustration of how the button should work.]

Here is an illustration of what they do not want:

[image: This is an illustration of what I'm not supposed to do.]

So is there anyway to do this? Oh yeah, one more thing: once this green button is pressed, it changes into a "Stop" button that is much smaller. The stop button should not be semi-transparent and the bar behind it should not have a chunk missing. In other words, I need to be able to turn this behavior on and off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue myself by creating a custom UIToolbar class:

DLYCustomToolbar.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UIToolbar+EEToolbarCenterButton.h"

@interface DLYCustomToolbar : UIToolbar

@property (nonatomic) bool isMasked;

@end
```

DLYCustomToolbar.m:

```
#import "DLYCustomToolbar.h"

@implementation DLYCustomToolbar

- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5] setFill];
    UIRectFill(rect);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);

    if(_isMasked) {
        float circleDiameter = 58;
        CGRect pathRect = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width/2-circleDiameter/2, -circleDiameter/2+2, circleDiameter, circleDiameter);
        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:pathRect];
        [path fill];
    }

    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
}

- (void) setIsMasked:(bool)isMasked {
    if (isMasked != _isMasked) {
        _isMasked = isMasked;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

@end
```